# what is the use of api,php in laravel 5,4

Tags: php, api, authentication, laravel-5, routes

```
use Illuminate\Http\Request;

/*
|-----------------------------------------------------------------------
| API Routes
|-----------------------------------------------------------------------        |
| Here is where you can register API routes for your application. These
| routes are loaded by the RouteServiceProvider within a group which
| is assigned the "api" middleware group. Enjoy building your API!
|
*/

Route::middleware('auth:api')->get('/user', function (Request $request) {
    return $request->user();
```

--what is the purpose of this api.php in laravel 5.4. and how can i used in our projects....?---

Comment: This is for stateless requests.

Comment: https://laravel.com/docs/5.4/routing @kavi

Comment: The api is just another route group that Laravel comes with. You can define different middleware to run for different route groups. Check `Kernel.php` to see which middleware runs for which group.

Answer (score 5):

simplified:

routes/web.php => are the routes for people with browsers => pretty pages with inputs, colors, fancy stuff

routes/api.php => are the routes for applications who needs/wants data from your app/website => key/value data only

Answer (score 0):

All Laravel routes are defined in your route files, which are located in the routes directory. These files are automatically loaded by the framework. The routes/web.php file defines routes that are for your web interface. These routes are assigned the web middleware group, which provides features like session state and CSRF protection. The routes in routes/api.php are stateless and are assigned the api middleware group.

Answer (score 0):

`routes/api.php` file is used when you want to make a [Restful API](https://www.sitepoint.com/developers-rest-api/) . It means that you are developing the front end of your project with something else(for example: angular) and you want to develope your back end using Laravel.

In that case your all routes will go in `routes/api.php`. All of these routes in most cases use POST method. Although if you want to make tests and see response of those routes in your browser then you can use `GET` method in your route and access browser with `api/` suffix like: `your_laravel_public_url/api/your_route` as Laravel adds `api/` suffix automatically.

Whereas if you are building your front end with Laravel as well then most likely you will define your routes in `app/web.php` with `GET` methods.

As a conclusion we can say that a web project made fully in Laravel, utilizes `routes/web.php` (for GET requests) as well as `routes/api.php` (for POST requests) while if you are making a RESTful API with Laravel then all of your routes will go in `routes/api.php`.

Again its not a hard and fast rule..you can go with `routes/web.php` always no matter what but at least that's the convention.

Comment: I know this is an old thread but is it possible to use routes/web.php for frontend framework like angular to call the routes instead of routes.api.php?